# OR-Tools: Unused Vehicles Occupying Depot Capacity in VRPTW with Resource Constraints

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I'm testing VRPTW with Resource Constraints example from [official website](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrptw_resources).
Everything is fine except for 1 thing:
If I set too many vehicles in data model and that will cause some unused vehicles and unused routes. **Unused vehicles will still occupy depot capacity** and cause inefficient routes planning. In my case, I'd rather like vehicles not to occupy depot capacity when they're unused.

In the following mock example, vehicle 0 & 1 occupied depot and caused postponing departure for vehicle 2 & 3.

```
Route for vehicle 0:
0 Time(0,0) -> 0 Time(20,20)
Time of the route: 20min

Route for vehicle 1:
0 Time(5,5) -> 0 Time(25,25)
Time of the route: 20min

Route for vehicle 2:
0 Time(10,10) -> 1 Time(17,17) -> 2 Time(25,25) -> 0 Time(30,30)
Time of the route: 20min

Route for vehicle 3:
0 Time(15,15) -> 3 Time(17,20) -> 4 Time(30,30) -> 0 Time(35,35)
Time of the route: 20min
```

In my case, **I'd rather like vehicles not to occupy depot when they're unused**. Does anyone know how to do that?

I have try to add `solver.IsVehicleUsed` and `solver.IsDifferentCstCt` into the following constraints but failed. Please help (examples would be much appreciated), Thanks!

```
depot_usage = [1 for i in range(len(intervals))]
   solver.Add(
       solver.Cumulative(intervals, depot_usage, data['depot_capacity'], 'depot'))
```

Comment: i also face this issue. my solution is when i have number of vehicle in request, i do for loop for vehicle from 1 to `total vehicle`, loop will stop when i found the unused vehicle. then i know how much vehicle i need in reality